# XML parser for different RSS files

Tags: php, xml, rss

For parsing XML files I use Simple XML. But for every XML file I write diffrent function, because of some XML have diffrent tags.

But how popular services parse xml? For example RSS Reader and etc. They just parse and slice additional images and videos and show it in additional block.

Comment: You need to share your code exemplary otherwise it's not really clear. As far as RSS itself is concerned, you only need one parser that supports all of the features, see http://cyber.law.harvard.edu/rss/rss.html - Probably one for each RSS version. For some extensions to it and/or for parsing embedded HTML, you need to decide your own how to do that, but normally you can streamline this as well, so technically it's not one parser per RSS feed, but one parser for all that's improved over time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

RSS readers only read RSS feeds. RSS feeds are XML documents with a certain standard, so to parse RSS feeds, only a certain number of standards need to be parsed. For more information see: [RSS - Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSS)

Keep in mind that RSS feeds are XML documents, but not every XML document is a RSS feed.

Reading your questing it looks like you have a variety of different XML documents with their own structure, to parse these you don't really have any other option but to build custom parse logic for each of these.

Comment: Okey, I haven't explained well. Some rss feeds have this <img>link</img> and other have <media:image>link</media> and what I need to do with this?

Comment: @Berny - According to the [2.0 spec](http://www.rssboard.org/rss-specification), the correct tag is `<image>`. Are you really talking about RSS?

Comment: As I mentioned in my answer, there are a certain number of standards and versions of those standard that RSS readers have implemented like RSS1.0, RSS2.0 ATOM0.3, ATOM1.0 etc etc

Comment: Btw, most use media tag eith atributes, but some use image tag.